# Waterline : Trying to access a collection string that is not defined

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I use Waterline with Sails.js.

I want to have a **User** that has **Involvements** . An **Event** can have multiple **Involvements**. An **Involvement** has a status.

My **User** class :

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
    involvements: {
        collection: 'Involvement',
        via : 'user'
    }
}
};
```

My **Event** class :

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
    creator: {
        model: 'User'
    },
    involvements: {
        collection: 'Involvement',
        via: 'event'
    }
}
};
```

My **Involvement** class :

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
    status: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    user : {
        model : 'User'
    },
    event : {
        model : 'Event'
    }
}
};
```

When I try to start my server I have this error :

> Trying to access a collection string that is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating Sails to a newer version. I tried this on Sails 0.11.0 and it worked fine, so I'm guessing there might have been a problem with circular relationships.

`npm update sails`

or if it's installed globally:

`sudo npm update -g sails`

Comment: It does not change anything. Does it can be a problem on my models ?

Comment: @damienmarchand: Shouldn't be a problem with the models because I tried them out and they worked fine. What database driver and version are you using? Mention the sails version too, preferably in your question itself.

Comment: I 'm sorry. I wrote model : 'string' instead of type : 'string' in on of my other models.

Comment: Ah, that's a nasty one. Glad you spotted it.

Comment: Couldn't help sharing this: I was fiddling around with a few models and eventually spent the last half hour trying to debug this exact issue in my current project. Ended up compromising the test database as well. Big facepalm at the end.